# Grade version 2.6 required. Current version is 2.4

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use the experimental plugin to build NDK via Android Studio.

- I have checked my "Open Module Settings->Project->Gradle version" and confirmed it is 2.6
- gradle-wrapper.properties contains:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip`

- android.project\build.gradle contains:

  classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha7"
- My C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle folder contains all gradle versions from gradle-2.4 thru gradle-2.8

Why does Android Studio continue to think that Gradle 2.4 is installed/in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the preference page `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`? Perhaps `Use local gradle distribution` is checked with an old Gradle version specified in the `Gradle Home:` field.

Comment: I will check those if it happens again.. I searched for all 2.4 refernences and found some in my .idea XML files (there were 2 files but I can't remember their names). That seems to have solved that problem.. but I have another...